# My font does not render correctly in IE11

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

For some reason my font does not correctly render in IE11, but is fine in Chrome. Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'LT_21152';
  src: url('../../fonts/LT_21152.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Try to look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174622/font-face-not-working-with-specific-version-of-internet-explorer-11

Comment: use .eot format. Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Upload your font in https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator