# My font does not work in IE11

Tags: html, css, fonts

My font does not work in IE11 and I was wondering if anyone out there knew why?

```
   @font-face {
     font-family: myFont;
     src: url('LT_21152.eot');
   }

   @font-face { 
     font-family: myFont;
     src: url('LT_21152.ttf');
   }

   font-family: myFont, myFont_IE, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

   div {
     font-family: myFont;
     font-size: 2em;
   }
```

Comment: Do you have a WOFF or OTF file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face not working with specific version of Internet Explorer 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174622/font-face-not-working-with-specific-version-of-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Have you tried adding `format('embedded-opentype')` to your EOT extension of the font?

Comment: I've found this, which I'll investigate further: CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.CSS3114)

Comment: Also don't use this syntax for `@font-face`. Even with the embedding permissions fixed, use one rule, with multiple sources, so `src: url('moo.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('moo.ttf') format('truetype'), url(.....`, but more importantly: IE11 does **not** need .eot, only IE8 and below do, and you don't want to use .ttf, that's a system font format, subject to way stricter validation. For IE11, and all modern browsers, use WOFF.