# Internet Explorer 11 crash when using font-face

Tags: internet-explorer-11, font-face

I understand that there are many issues regarding font-face and IE, 
after reading everything i have a very weird problem:
this is very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174622/font-face-not-working-with-specific-version-of-internet-explorer-11).
i narrowed the crash (ie has stoped working) to this css:

```
/* Droid Sans Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid_sans';
    src: url('fonts/DroidSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/DroidSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/DroidSans-Bold-webfont.svg#droid_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('fonts/DroidSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DroidSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

it seems that when i change the last line format to: format('eot') ie dose NOT crash.
this only happens in IE with windows 8 (8.1), on windows 10+ie11 there is no crash.
cannot figure out if it is ok to keep it with that format?
the site is hosted on sharepoint online (so no iis to access)

IE version: 11.0.9600.18639
update version: 11.0.41

font download is enabled
thanks

Comment: Why do you don't using google fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Droid+Sans ?

Comment: becose the enviorment will not have access to google servers.