# Font support on IE 11

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a problem with font on IE 11. Some of my element can't accept `font-family`. I had `.woff` and `.woff2` but it's not accepting my fonts. How can I solve this?
Here's my CSS code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;

  src: url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Roboto Thin'), local('Roboto-Thin'),
  url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

And I'm using the `font-family` rule like below:

```
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

Here is a result:

[image: Failure]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174622/font-face-not-working-with-specific-version-of-internet-explorer-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174622/font-face-not-working-with-specific-version-of-internet-explorer-11) check if it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're assuming `Roboto` is a built-in web font, which it's not. You need quotation marks:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

Comment: Look in Developer Tools and find out which styles are being applied to the text, and look from there. Or could you please post your entire HTML + CSS code?

Comment: My given style applied all texts but some elements can not accepting it

Comment: What versions of HTML are you using?

Comment: HTML5 here is screen when i uncheck style http://tinyimg.io/i/JkoS0Xp.PNG

Comment: I agree, it seems to work in Safari. Maybe add an IE declaration (like `-webkit-` but for IE)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the network tab in DevTools (F12)? You shouldn't have any 404 at load.

If you support IE10+ (IE9- isn't supported by MS itself), you only need WOFF2 and WOFF formats. SVG for example is for iOS3-4 or something like that…

You should first test with an uncommon font family name and super normal parameters (no italic, no thin or bold):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'test';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;

  src: url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../../webfonts/roboto/roboto-v18-cyrillic-ext_latin-100.woff') format('woff') /* Modern Browsers */
;
}

body,
body * {
  font-family: 'test' !important;
}
```

It allows you to test for correct path relative to your CSS (compiled CSS if you use Sass and _partials or LESS or PostCSS or Stylus!).
Then you can add `font-weight: 100;` to both your @-declaration and rules (and remove test bits like body * and !important :p) .
Then change the name of the font family.

Comment: I solved my problem. It was the `font-weight: problem` btw thanks :)